# Horizontal Scrollbar customization for IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, scrollbar

I am facing one issue regarding horizontal scrollbar in IE.I want to decrease height of horizontal scrollbar. I have already customized it in Chrome but that style is not getting applied in IE.

CSS:

```
  .scrollbar-style::-webkit-scrollbar {
        height: 5px !important;
    }
```

Can anybody please advise if they have worked on customizing scrollbar in IE?

Answer (score 0):

It only work for webkit browsers.

In the documentation, It is mentioned that it is non standard.

> Non-standard
>   This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

It is not supported by Internet Explorer, So it is not working on it.

Reference:

[scrollbar](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar/)

[::-webkit-scrollbar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar)